# Is there any way to extend Identity server 4 Client table to add extra column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

Implementing Identity server 4, and have to add extra column in Client table. Is there any possibility extend Client class in order to add column in table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add new column in Client table in IdentityServer 4 using CodeFirst approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911337/how-to-add-new-column-in-client-table-in-identityserver-4-using-codefirst-approa)

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911337/how-to-add-new-column-in-client-table-in-identityserver-4-using-codefirst-approa/58911787

Comment: @mackie As per that question. its not possible :(. I am looking for any other solution

Comment: Can you explain why it's not possible? From a technical PoV, without forking `identityserver4` it's the only possible approach.

Comment: @mackie unable to extend the Client model like IdentityUser model. When  added and apply migration it creating whole new Client table in db. I want to add a column in existing Client table.

Comment: My answer was just pointing out that `ClientProperties` exists so there's no need to extend the model. The framework does not support extending the model in any other way. These are exposed via the `Properties` property of the `IdentityServer4.Models.Client` class.

Comment: @mackie How to access those `Properties` property in login page of `IdentityServer4`?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu  `IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl)` is the method you need. Takes the `/connect/authorize` url that'll be passed to your sign in action via the query string. To get the full client model (including those properties) you'd pass the `ClientId` you get back to `IClientStore.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(id)`

Comment: Thank you @mackie It is working as expected. My `LogoutId` is always null and I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Hybrid client application. I have passed `id_token_hint` but, it is not working. Can you assist me on this?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to build a new class that inherits from the IdentityServer Client class? I guess that would work! [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance)

Comment: yeah tried but not working. So you have any working example?